# I try to run MLE, and get the Error in if (!all(lower[isfixed] <= fixed[isfixed] & fixed[isfixed] <= : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, mle

I try to run MLE, and get the

> Error in if (!all(lower[isfixed] <= fixed[isfixed] & fixed[isfixed] <=  :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed constantly,

The negative likelihood function

```
likelihood.normal <- function (mu,sigma,y ){
  pdf_yt <- dnorm(y, mu, sigma, log= FALSE) 
  -sum(log(pdf_yt))
}
```

The MLE command

```
library(stats4)
est.normal<-c(est$mean, est$sd)
bound.lower <-est.normal*0.5 # set the lower bound for the method "L-BFGS-B"
bound.upper <-est.normal*2.0 # set the upper bound for the method "L-BFGS-B"

est.mle<-mle(minuslogl =likelihood.normal, start= list(mu = est$mean, sigma = est$sd),method="L-BFGS-B",fixed = list(y= return.log), lower=bound.lower, upper= bound.upper)
```

If the fixed parameter is removed, the issue is gone. But I need the fixed parameter.

Comment: `est` and `return.log` are not defined, your code is not reproducible. Can you post values for `est.normal` and `return.log`?

Comment: welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I too came across this error, and I believe it to be due to package dependency issues within the stats4::mle package.

When I submitted the project, I took a functional approach instead. Create a function that generates a function of the parameters with the data already preset as in the following:

```
logLikelihood.Norm.Function <- function (y) {
    logLikelihood.ParamFunc <- function (mu, sigma) {
        n <- length(y)
        pdf_yt <- dnorm(y, mu, sigma, log = FALSE)
        log.likelihood.value <- -sum(log(pdf_yt))
        return(log.likelihood.value)
    }
    return(logLikelihood.ParamFunc)
}
```

Comment: Thank you James for your great response. May you share your MLE command to call logLikelihood.Norm.Function?

Comment: Leave a reply to axeman1293's comment on https://www.reddit.com/r/actuary/comments/xmniyf/qfi_fmm/. From there you can get help with all scenario modeling questions.

Comment: Perfect! I commented in the link you mentioned, but at the same time, kept trying, and it works now! Thank you very much, James!